# How to upload a multer file as a blob in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, blob, multer

I'm trying to store a file uploaded into a nodejs server into a mysql database. The file is uploaded and processed using a [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) middleware, thus storing all the file information in `req.files`. I believe, correct me if I am mistaken, that this data/parameters must be somehow converted to a blob format yet I do not know how to do so effectively. How could this be done in order to upload it into a MySQL database?

I am using the latest version of XAMPP with a MySQL InnoDB tables. The file parameters/data generated by Multer are shown in the code snippet. I've attempted converting the entire file, that is `req.files[0]`, into a blob yet the blobs stored in the MySQL database are identical in size despite using different files.

```
[ { fieldname: 'files',
    originalname: 'Event Information 2018-1_2084.pdf',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/pdf',
    destination:
     '/home/millana/Desktop/Brandink/Code/server/middleware/../designs/',
    filename: 'Event Information 2018-1_2084_1559843587360.pdf',
    path:
     '/home/millana/Desktop/Brandink/Code/server/designs/Event Information 2018-1_2084_1559843587360.pdf',
    size: 1125992 } ]
```

Below is shown the restAPI called to execute the query on an already existing table `Designs` and database.

```
router.post('/order', upload.array('files'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files[0].buffer);

    const order_id = 1;
    const position = 'front';

    const sql = `INSERT INTO Designs VALUES ('${order_id}', '${position}', '${req.files[0].filename}', '${req.files[0].mimetype}', '${req.files[0].buffer}')`;


    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) res.status(400).send(err);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });

});
```

The middleware function includes:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null,  __dirname + '/../designs/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let format = '';

        if      ( file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' )      format = '.jpg';
        else if ( file.mimetype === 'image/png' )       format = '.png';
        else if ( file.mimetype === 'application/pdf' ) format = '.pdf';


        let fileName = _.split(file.originalname, '.')[0] + '_' + Date.now() + format;
        cb(null, fileName);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: MAX_SIZE
    },
});
```

I expect the blob size to vary from one file to another proportionally with their file size. However, the size for all files uploaded is of 9 bytes while the buffers are identical, indicating that the same object/file is being stored. How can I store each different file accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

How about using fileFilter? You can manage the quality of file, or size etc. 
https://github.com/expressjs/multer

As you see in links or your knowledge, multer has some options like fileFilter or limits.
fileFilter, is similar to your function, to select file type.
limits,

fileSize : {
    5 * 1024 * 1024
}

And I've heard that storing files like image is to convert a binary file in a buffer.

if you console.log(img file), you can see the output such as 
Binary {
        _bsontype: 'Binary',
        sub_type: 0,
        position: 260547,
        buffer:  } }

then change array Buffer to base64, string. 
the result is,
data : image/jpeg;base64, v9emlk3SGF45fg...

It is different from 'filename or originalName',

so it could be saved as a different one.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @U10-Forward I'm one of programmers between beginner and intermediate. And this question has not touched for 8 months and I attached multer.js API docu. So I cannot add more perfect than official one. So I added simple answers ground by my exp and links.

Comment: Okay, but please provide a bit more info, make it make sense even when you read it without a link

Comment: @U10-Forward Thank you for your advice. I cannot confirm that my words can be solution or not. So I want to add comments, but my reward points,,, as you see.. So I just uphold my suggestion with official docu. I think my answer is awkward one, but just want to be a hint and would be better than 'no answer'.